# Estou dando vários setText() em um mesmo TextView mas só é mostrado a ultima modificação?

Tags: java, android, textview

já pesquisei em tudo quanto é canto e não achei alguém com o mesmo problema que eu. Deve ser algo muito bobo mas realmente não estou conseguindo ver o que é.
Eu estou fazendo um RPG textual, eu cheguei numa parte onde ocorre um embate com o um Lobo, que nem na tela abaixo, minha intenção era fazer um TextView que dissesse o que está acontecendo durante o combate, mas estou esbarrando no problema citado no título.

[Foto da minha Activity "Fight"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvQ1Q.png)

A textView descrevendo o que está acontecendo no combate está embaixo da barra de HP do Lobo (que tbm está com problemas, mas queria corrigir esse problema do texto primeiro).

Eu sinto que estou sendo trollado/sacaneado por alguma mecânica de otimização do Android (que estaria "otimizando" meu código fazendo apenas o ultimo setText() que pedi..) mas realmente não faço ideia.

```
public void atacarComRightHand(View view) {

    int x = 85*action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).armor;
    x = Math.round(x/600);

    Integer danoAlcancado = Math.round(action_activity.armas.right_hand.ataque - (action_activity.armas.right_hand.ataque*x)/100);

    action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).hp = action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).hp - danoAlcancado;
    action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).hp = Math.max(action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).hp, 0);

    if (action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).hp <= 0) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).nome + " morto!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        finish();
    }
    else {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descricaoGolpeFight);
        tv.setText((CharSequence) ("Dano de " + danoAlcancado.toString() + " no " + action_activity.localAtual.monstros
                .get(0).nome + "!"));

        ProgressBar pgb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarFight);
        int y = Math.round((100 * action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).hp) / action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).hpMax);

        pgb.setProgress(y);

        int cont = 0;
        while (cont < 2000000000) {
            cont++;
        }
        
        tv.setText((CharSequence) (action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).nome + " revida o ataque.."));

        action_activity.hp = action_activity.hp - action_activity.localAtual.monstros.get(0).ataque;

        cont = 0;
        while (cont < 1000000000) {
            cont++;
        }
        
        tv.setText((CharSequence) "");

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hpRestanteFight);
        tv.setText((CharSequence) ("HP: " + action_activity.hp + "/" + action_activity.hpMax));
    }
}
```

No código eu calculo o dano obtido no Lobo e informo o usuario de quanto foi o dano e em quem foi, depois disso eu calculo o quanto resta de vida em % no lobo e tento atualizar a barra de life.
Em seguida verifico se o lobo morreu, se morreu solto um pequeno aviso dizendo que morreu e logo depois encerro a activity (com isso o jogo volta pro menu principal, a "action_activity"), caso contrário eu aguardo alguns segundos  e  então faço o turno do lobo e calculo o dano dele no personagem, e informo novamente na mesma textView o dano tomado, espero meio segundo +/- e limpo a informação textual com um novo setText(). Além de atualizar o life do personagem no finalzinho.

Desses três setText() só aparece o ultimo (ou seja, texto em branco), se eu comento os últimos dois, o primeiro aparece, se eu comento só o ultimo, o segundo setText() é quem aparece.

Se precisarem de mais informações vão pedindo que eu posto, postei só isso pq o app já tá ficando bem grande e é só essa parte que está "bugando" por enquanto.

Comecei a programar android a um mês atrás, realmente n manjo das ferramentas ainda. =/
Alguém ai sabe a solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar cada alteração do `setText()` vc tem que fazer isso em uma Thread , pois ao executar esse código na Thread Principal ele só mostrara a ultima alteração.

**Passo 1: Acrescente final no tv**

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descricaoGolpeFight);
```

**Passo 2: Crie a Thread**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   
   }
}).start();
```

Agr dentro do `run()` vc faz os próximos passos.

Troque isso:

```
int cont = 0;
    while (cont < 2000000000) {
        cont++;
    }
```

Por isso:

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

e toda vez que for usar o `setText()` precisa estar dentro de:

```
(SuaActivity).this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
      public void run() {
        tv.setText((CharSequence) ("Dano de " + danoAlcancado.toString() + " no " + action_activity.localAtual.monstros
                .get(0).nome + "!"));       
      }
});
```

E no final crie o tv2 pois o tv não pode ser alterado:

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hpRestanteFight);
        tv2.setText((CharSequence) ("HP: " + action_activity.hp + "/" + action_activity.hpMax));
```

Comment: Pior que era isso mesmo brother, vi em outro fórum e esqueci que havia feito a pergunta aqui. Agradeço a todos pelas respostas. Faltava esse lance de Threads mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou dar um Thread.sleep(5000)? Isso faz com que a thread pare de executar e a tela trave pelo tempo desejado.

Obs: 5000 nesse caso é milissegundos, então pode ser mais ou menos, depende de como você quer.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).